# Editing a userprofile on django

Tags: django

How to create a userprofile editable page and upon clicking submission it updates the details provided during registration(the details stored in the database) using DJANGO?.

Creation of registration form for a user, and like i have said in my opening post, i want the user after he must have logged in to able to edit what he provided during registration and it will update the previous details stored in the database.

I know i need to create a view for it, but have not arrived at how to call on the details provided during registration. Well maybe using user.get_profile()

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from registeredmember.models import Registeredmember


class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    first_name      = forms.CharField(label=(u'First Name'))
    middle_name     = forms.CharField(label=(u'Middle Name'))
    last_name       = forms.CharField(label=(u'Last Name'))
    occupation      = forms.CharField(label=(u'Occupation'))
    income          = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Income Amount'))
    age             = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Age'))
    address_line1   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Address line 1'))
    address_line2   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Address line 2'))
    city            = forms.CharField(label=(u'City'))
    state           = forms.CharField(label=(u'State'))
    phone_no_Mobile = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Phone Number (Home)'))
    phone_no_Work   = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Phone Number (Work)'))
    purpose         = forms.CharField(label=(u'Purpose'))
    username        = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
    email           = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
    password        = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password1       = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    class Meta:
        model = Registeredmember
        exclude = ('user','reference_number',)
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError('That username is already taken, please select another.')


    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        try:
            User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError('That email address is already in the database, please provide another.')

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username    = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'),widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '30'}))
    password    = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

## views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from registeredmember.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from registeredmember.models import Registeredmember 
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
import random, time
from random import randint








def userregistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email = form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.save()
            registeredmember = Registeredmember(user=user, prefix = form.cleaned_data['prefix'],first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],\
                                                middle_name=form.cleaned_data['middle_name'],last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],gender=form.cleaned_data['gender'],\
                                                occupation=form.cleaned_data['occupation'],income=form.cleaned_data['income'],age=form.cleaned_data['age'],\
                                                address_line1=form.cleaned_data['address_line1'],address_line2=form.cleaned_data['address_line2'],city=form.cleaned_data['city'],\
                                                state=form.cleaned_data['state'],phone_no_Mobile=form.cleaned_data['phone_no_Mobile'],phone_no_Work=form.cleaned_data['phone_no_Work'],\
                                                purpose=form.cleaned_data['purpose'])


            registeredmember.save()



            return render_to_response('carloan/regsuccessful.html',{'ref_no': ref_no}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('carloan/register.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        '''user is not submitting the form, show them a blank registration form'''
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render_to_response('carloan/register.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


@login_required
def Profile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    registeredmember = request.user.get_profile
    return render_to_response('carloan/profile.html', {'registeredmember': registeredmember}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))



def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            registeredmember = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if registeredmember is not None:
                login(request, registeredmember)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
            else:
                return render_to_response('carloan/loginerror.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            '''user is submitting a blank login form, notify him that he submitted a blank form''' 
            return render_to_response('carloan/loginblank.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        '''user is not submitting the form, show the login form'''
        form = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('carloan/login.html',{'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def LogoutRequest(request):
    logout(request)
    return render_to_response('carloan/logout.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## The code below gives the error username already exists, but when i specify a new username it updates although it doesn't update the username but the other fields

## views.py for the editprofile

```
@login_required
def editprofile(request):
    registeredmember = request.user.get_profile()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userprofile_edit = RegistrationForm(request.POST, instance = registeredmember)
        if userprofile_edit.is_valid():
            userprofile_edit.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        userprofile_edit = RegistrationForm(instance = registeredmember)
    return render_to_response('carloan/editprofile.html', {'userprofile_edit': userprofile_edit}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## Got it sorted out with codes below:

## forms.py

```
class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Registeredmember
        exclude = ('user','username','email','password','password1',)
```

## views.py

```
@login_required
def editprofile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userprofile_edit = EditForm(request.POST, instance = request.user.get_profile())
        if userprofile_edit.is_valid():
            userprofile_edit.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        userprofile_edit = EditForm(instance = request.user.get_profile())
    return render_to_response('carloan/editprofile.html', {'userprofile_edit': userprofile_edit}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thank you all...

Comment: I'd guess you'd need to write some code. That would be a good start.

Comment: i have done that already

Comment: It is very generic question, maybe you could paste your code here and point the parts you are missing.

Comment: Please take a closer look at my OP, i have modified it.

Comment: This is a problem that on Django 1.5 should be almost solved with the custom user model feature. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model

Comment: if you exclude password field will it update if user tries to update its password?

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.5 and custom user models will help with this, but in the mean time your ModelForm set up is fine.

To initialize a ModelForm from an instance of its object, do this:

```
user_profile_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.get_profile())
```

The `request.POST` in that line allows you to update the `user_profile_form` object with the user's input. It will nicely merge the existing data from your instance with the new info from the user.

You can then print this to a view, or you can save it doing this:

```
if user_profile_form.is_valid():
    user_profile_form.save()
else
    # do other stuff
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, please see the edited version above. I have done like you suggested, but getting the error username already exists, but when i specify a new username it updates although it doesn't update the username but the other fields.